# T-sql Percent calculation stuffed with WHERE clauses doesn't work

Tags: t-sql

I have t-sql as follows:

```
SELECT (COUNT(Intakes.fk_ClientID) * 100) / (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM INTAKES
        WHERE Intakes.AdmissionDate >= @StartDate
        )
FROM Intakes
WHERE Intakes.fk_ReleasedFromID = '1'
    AND Intakes.AdmissionDate >= @StartDate;
```

I'm trying to get the percentage of clients who have releasedfromID = 1 out of a subset of clients who have a certain range of admission dates.  But I get rows of 1's and 0's instead.  Now, I can get the percentage if I take out the where clauses, it works:

```
SELECT (COUNT(Intakes.fk_ClientID) * 100) / (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM INTAKES
        )
FROM Intakes
WHERE Intakes.fk_ReleasedFromID = '1';
```

works fine.  It selects ClientIDs where ReleasedFromID =1, multiplies it by 100 and divides by total rows in Intakes.  But how do you run percentage with WHERE clauses as above?

Comment: Is it integer division being at issue? Try multiplying the first term by 1.0 to get the math into floating point territory first.

Answer (score 0):

After reading comment from @Anssssss

```
SELECT (COUNT(Intakes.fk_ClientID) * 100.0) / (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM INTAKES
        ) 'percentage'
FROM Intakes
WHERE Intakes.fk_ReleasedFromID = '1';
```